# How to parse doc comments

Tags: php, string, reflection, comments

I'm using reflection to get the doc comment from a method:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php, which looks like this:

```
   /** 
    * Method description
    *
    * @param  array $foo    Bla bla
    * @return string        More bla bla
    */
```

How can I parse this string into something that I can work with?
I need to extract the "Method description" text from it. The other stuff is not important to me, because I can use other reflection methods to get the parameters etc.

Comment: Not sure if this will be useful to you, but have you looked into [phpDocumenter](http://www.phpdoc.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
trim(str_replace(array('/', '*'), '', substr($rc->getDocComment(), 0, strpos($rc->getDocComment(), '@'))));
```

Assuming the comments are always in that format.

Answer (score 1):

I've not had much experience with parsing comments, however, treating this as a string, what I'd do is:

1. Explode by new lines:
2. trim spaces and * out

Something like this:

```
<?php

$string = "   /** 
    * Method description
    *
    * @param  array $foo    Bla bla
    * @return string        More bla bla
    */";

$parts = explode("\n",$string);
$comment = trim($parts[1]," *");
echo $comment; // will echo "Method description"
```

However, probably isn't ideal as the description might be on more than one line.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function parseAnnotations($doc){

    preg_match_all('/@([a-z]+?)\s+(.*?)\n/i', $doc, $annotations);

    if(!isset($annotations[1]) OR count($annotations[1]) == 0){
        return [];
    }

    return array_combine(array_map("trim",$annotations[1]), array_map("trim",$annotations[2]));
}
```

...

```
$reflection = new ReflectionObject($class);
foreach($reflection->getProperties() as $property){
   print_r($this->parseAnnotations($property->getDocComment()));
}
```

example

```
/** 
* @param $action
* @required FALSE
*/
private $action;
```

result

```
Array
(
  [param] => $action
  [required] => FALSE
)
```