# how to use preg_match for multiline string to find some values

Tags: php, preg-match

I would find some values in multiline string before i will parse this string to functionaly form (array):

```
 /**
 * @type string
 * @access read|write
 * @filling true
 */
```

How can i find in this string every 3 values (@type, @access and @filling)
i tried use something like:

```
 preg_match('/^.*@type{1}.*@access{1}.*@filling{1}.*$/',$string);
```

but isnt work. Anybody have idea for fix this? I will greateful

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse doc comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461800/how-to-parse-doc-comments)

Comment: i know how to parse but before parse i would find this tree values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use capturing groups, plus `\S` instead of `.`, and `dotall` modifier:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^.*@type\s+(\S*).*@access\s+(\S*).*@filling\s+(\S*).*$/s',$string,$matches);

echo "type: $matches[1]\n";
echo "access: $matches[2]\n";
echo "filling: $matches[3]\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `.` doesn't match with whitespace(like tab, newline, space). You can provide new line explicitly by putting `\n` where necessary.

Comment: The only things that `.` doesn't match (by default) are newlines, all other white-characters are matched.